# What if the difference between Map method of IApplicationBuilder and Map method of IEndpointRouteBuilder in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, routes, endpoint

Since `WebApplication` implement both of `IApplicationBuilder` and `IEndpointRouteBuilder` there is a `Map` method for application with multiple overloads specially `Map(string pattern,Action<IApplicationBuilder>)` and `Map(string pattern, RequestDelegate requestDelegate)`. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Although thy have same name, they have almost different purposes and overload. The map method of application builder `(Map(string pattern,Action<IApplicationBuilder>))` first create a new app using `IApplicationBuilder.New()` method and then apply to this new Application, the configuration defined in Map method using `Action<IApplicationBuilder>` configuration. At the end it use the Build method of New IApplication and create a request delegate. Then invoke this delegate using path matched as base path and remaining path as path in a middleware named `MapMiddleware` (it has nothing except setting and resetting basepath and path from passed one to matched one and reverse! and invoking the built request delegate).
See following link:

[IApplicationBuilder Map](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs)

But The Map method of `IEndpointRouteBuilder` (`Map(string/RoutePattern pattern, RequestDelegate requestDelegate))` first create a new `RouteEndpointBuilder()` with `order=0` and `displayname` as pattern raw text from pattern and delegate. Then add attributes of `RequestDelegate` if any (in class based request delegate like controllers) to builder. Then it check if there is any `EndpointDataSource` exist for `IEndpointRouteBuilder` and if not create one (for example using new `ModelEndpointDataSource()`) and add it to `IEndpointRouteBuilder.DataSources`. At the end it build an `IEndpointConventionBuilder` from the `RouteEndPointBuilder` for example using `new DefaultEndpointConventionBuilder(endpointBuilder)` and it to data source (Actually it should build the route endpoint and it to data source but we can implement the getter for endpoints in a way that read from convention builder) and Finally return that convention builder to do more work on it. see following:

[IEndpointRouteBuilder Map Method](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bf03cee1625eb74939b28ea6b79b4a994b926421/src/Http/Routing/src/Builder/EndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs)

Comment: But when to use which one?

Comment: Personally, I think, If you want to do branching in your middle-ware pipeline base on first segment of your url path use IApplicationBuilder.Map and if you want to use one main pipeline with different endpoints route use IEnddpointRouteBuilder.Map method. The second one implemented by Map... methods (for example MapControllerRoute) of the Application Builder but if you want to implement your own logic with HTTPContext you can use Map (second one) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Main differences:

- `IApplicationBuilder.Map` branches based on **start** of the url, while `IEndpointRouteBuilder.Map` branches based on the **full** url
- `IEndpointRouteBuilder.Map` handler is always **terminal** while `IApplicationBuilder.Map` allows further pipeline execution by calling `next.Invoke()`